# I dont want background image to take up the full page CSS

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following css and I dont want the background image to take up the full height of the screen but I want the full width

```
.login-page, .register-page {
    background: url('https:/image/ex.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;        
}
```

Is there and easy way to do this or is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `background-size: 100% 60px;` For full width, you can give 100% and for the height, you can specify how much you want to cover. If you specify `auto` then it will take the height automatically based on your screen.

```css
.login-page, .register-page {
    background: url("https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/blue-background-with-reflective-lines_-13idtdxs__F0000.png");
   background-size: 100% auto; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="register-page">
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I dont want the image to stretch to that size if that makes sense?

Comment: Like I want a specific height and then the image to cover this height]

Comment: Ok .. so in this case, you can use background-size: 100% auto; which will take automatically. I have updated the snippet as well as.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `background-size` property from `cover` to `100% auto`:

```
.login-page, .register-page {
    background: url('https:/image/ex.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% auto;        
}
```

Which means: `100%` width and `auto` for the height.

Answer (score 1):

Give `background-size: 100% auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `width: 100%;background-size: 100% auto;` for the dom, and the background-image will expand to the relative height refer to the resolution ratio of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can use `background-size: 100% auto;` and maybe add some `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

here is my fiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/6w80jfc3/

good luck...